# Mysterious TypeError: no _dump_data is defined for class OpenSSL::Digest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

We've been seeing this error popping up more and more recently - but not consistently and are not able to reproduce it manually.
[image: errors spiking]

We have a standard Ruby on Rails app (5.2.3) on Ruby 2.6.5.

I have read all other posts with similar titles but I can't figure out where this is coming from, here our stacktrace:

```
/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/cache.rb:784 in dump
/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/cache.rb:784 in compress!
/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/cache.rb:722 in initialize
/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/cache.rb:445 in new
/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/cache.rb:445 in block in write
/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/cache.rb:663 in block in instrument
/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170 in instrument
/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/cache.rb:663 in instrument
/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/cache.rb:444 in write
/gems/ddtrace-0.29.1/lib/ddtrace/contrib/active_support/cache/instrumentation.rb:120 in write
/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/cache.rb:97 in _fetch
/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/cache.rb:87 in fetch
/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/cache.rb:81 in translate
/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/fallbacks.rb:41 in translate
/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n.rb:206 in block in translate
/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n.rb:202 in catch
/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n.rb:202 in translate
/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:146 in block in resolve
/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:143 in catch
/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:143 in resolve
/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:129 in block in default
/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:128 in each
/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:128 in default
/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:35 in translate
/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/cache.rb:81 in block in translate
/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/cache.rb:96 in catch
/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/cache.rb:96 in _fetch
/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/cache.rb:87 in fetch
/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/cache.rb:81 in translate
/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/fallbacks.rb:48 in block (2 levels) in translate
/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/fallbacks.rb:47 in catch
/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/fallbacks.rb:47 in block in translate
/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/fallbacks.rb:45 in each
/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/fallbacks.rb:45 in translate
/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n.rb:206 in block in translate
/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n.rb:202 in catch
/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n.rb:202 in translate
/gems/activemodel-5.2.3/lib/active_model/errors.rb:430 in generate_message
/gems/activemodel-5.2.3/lib/active_model/errors.rb:454 in normalize_message
/gems/activemodel-5.2.3/lib/active_model/errors.rb:298 in add
/gems/activemodel-5.2.3/lib/active_model/validations/presence.rb:7 in validate_each
/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/validations/presence.rb:10 in validate_each
/gems/activemodel-5.2.3/lib/active_model/validator.rb:152 in block in validate
/gems/activemodel-5.2.3/lib/active_model/validator.rb:149 in each
/gems/activemodel-5.2.3/lib/active_model/validator.rb:149 in validate
/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:426 in block in make_lambda
/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:179 in block (2 levels) in halting_and_conditional
/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:606 in block (2 levels) in default_terminator
/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:605 in catch
/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:605 in block in default_terminator
/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:180 in block in halting_and_conditional
/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:513 in block in invoke_before
/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:513 in each
/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:513 in invoke_before
/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:131 in run_callbacks
/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:816 in _run_validate_callbacks
/gems/activemodel-5.2.3/lib/active_model/validations.rb:409 in run_validations!
/gems/activemodel-5.2.3/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:118 in block in run_validations!
/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:132 in run_callbacks
/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:816 in _run_validation_callbacks
/gems/activemodel-5.2.3/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:118 in run_validations!
/gems/activemodel-5.2.3/lib/active_model/validations.rb:339 in valid?
/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/validations.rb:67 in valid?
/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/validations.rb:84 in perform_validations
/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/validations.rb:46 in save
/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:310 in block (2 levels) in save
/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:387 in block in with_transaction_returning_status
/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:265 in transaction
/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:212 in transaction
/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:385 in with_transaction_returning_status
/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:310 in block in save
/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:325 in rollback_active_record_state!
/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:309 in save
/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:44 in save
/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:428 in block in update
/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:387 in block in with_transaction_returning_status
/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:265 in transaction
/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:212 in transaction
/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:385 in with_transaction_returning_status
/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:426 in update
app/models/questionnaire/questionnaire_response.rb:290 in block in process_answers
288:    process_valid_blank_answer(answer)
289:  else
290:    answer.update(value: answer_attributes[:value])
291:    answers_errors[key] = answer.errors unless answer.valid?
292:  end
/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:338 in block in each_pair
/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:337 in each_pair
/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:337 in each_pair
app/models/questionnaire/questionnaire_response.rb:283 in process_answers
app/models/questionnaire/questionnaire_response.rb:218 in assign_params
app/models/questionnaire/questionnaire_response.rb:155 in save_draft
app/interactors/questionnaire/update_questionnaire_response.rb:53 in save_draft
app/interactors/questionnaire/update_questionnaire_response.rb:19 in call
/gems/interactor-3.1.2/lib/interactor.rb:143 in block in run!
/gems/interactor-3.1.2/lib/interactor/hooks.rb:213 in block in with_hooks
/gems/interactor-3.1.2/lib/interactor/hooks.rb:224 in run_around_hooks
/gems/interactor-3.1.2/lib/interactor/hooks.rb:211 in with_hooks
/gems/interactor-3.1.2/lib/interactor.rb:142 in run!
/gems/interactor-3.1.2/lib/interactor.rb:115 in run
/gems/interactor-3.1.2/lib/interactor.rb:50 in tap
/gems/interactor-3.1.2/lib/interactor.rb:50 in call
app/controllers/public_questionnaire_responses_controller.rb:56 in update_questionnaire_response
app/controllers/public_questionnaire_responses_controller.rb:31 in block in update
/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:267 in block in transaction
/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:239 in block in within_new_transaction
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:235 in mon_synchronize
/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:236 in within_new_transaction
/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:267 in transaction
/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:212 in transaction
app/controllers/public_questionnaire_responses_controller.rb:27 in update
/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6 in send_action
/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:194 in process_action
/gems/ddtrace-0.29.1/lib/ddtrace/contrib/action_pack/action_controller/instrumentation.rb:114 in process_action
/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30 in process_action
/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42 in block in process_action
/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:109 in block in run_callbacks
app/controllers/public_questionnaire_responses_controller.rb:122 in block in set_response_locale
/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n.rb:313 in with_locale
app/controllers/public_questionnaire_responses_controller.rb:122 in set_response_locale
/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118 in block in run_callbacks
/bundler/gems/grc_insight-4cd09d7a04d6/app/controllers/grc_insight/concerns/segment_io_monitoring.rb:46 in track_events
/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118 in block in run_callbacks
/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:136 in run_callbacks
/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41 in process_action
/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22 in process_action
/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:34 in block in process_action
/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168 in block in instrument
/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23 in instrument
/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168 in instrument
/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32 in process_action
/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:256 in process_action
/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24 in process_action
/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:134 in process
/gems/actionview-5.2.3/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:32 in process
/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:191 in dispatch
/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:252 in dispatch
/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:52 in dispatch
/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:34 in serve
/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:52 in block in serve
/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35 in each
/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35 in serve
/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:840 in call
/gems/flipper-0.16.2/lib/flipper/middleware/memoizer.rb:62 in memoized_call
/gems/flipper-0.16.2/lib/flipper/middleware/memoizer.rb:40 in call
/gems/flipper-0.16.2/lib/flipper/middleware/setup_env.rb:35 in call
/gems/warden-1.2.8/lib/warden/manager.rb:36 in block in call
/gems/warden-1.2.8/lib/warden/manager.rb:34 in catch
/gems/warden-1.2.8/lib/warden/manager.rb:34 in call
/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15 in call
/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/etag.rb:27 in call
/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:40 in call
/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/head.rb:12 in call
/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18 in call
/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266 in context
/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260 in call
/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:670 in call
/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28 in block in call
/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98 in run_callbacks
/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26 in call
/gems/airbrake-10.0.4/lib/airbrake/rack/middleware.rb:34 in call!
/gems/airbrake-10.0.4/lib/airbrake/rack/middleware.rb:23 in call
/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:61 in call
/gems/ddtrace-0.29.1/lib/ddtrace/contrib/rails/middlewares.rb:17 in call
/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33 in call
/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38 in call_app
/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26 in block in call
/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71 in block in tagged
/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28 in tagged
/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71 in tagged
/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26 in call
/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81 in call
/gems/request_store-1.5.0/lib/request_store/middleware.rb:19 in call
/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27 in call
/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/method_override.rb:24 in call
/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22 in call
/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29 in call
/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14 in call
/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127 in call
/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110 in call
/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/ssl.rb:74 in call
/gems/ddtrace-0.29.1/lib/ddtrace/contrib/rack/middlewares.rb:85 in call
/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:524 in call
/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:190 in public_send
/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:190 in method_missing
/gems/unicorn-5.5.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:605 in process_client
/gems/unicorn-5.5.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:700 in worker_loop
/gems/unicorn-5.5.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:548 in spawn_missing_workers
/gems/unicorn-5.5.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:144 in start
/gems/unicorn-5.5.3/bin/unicorn:128 in <top (required)>
/bin/unicorn:23 in load
/bin/unicorn:23 in <top (required)>
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74 in load
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74 in kernel_load
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28 in run
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:465 in exec
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27 in run
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126 in invoke_command
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387 in dispatch
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:27 in dispatch
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466 in start
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:18 in start
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/exe/bundle:30 in block in <top (required)>
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:124 in with_friendly_errors
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/exe/bundle:22 in <top (required)>
/usr/local/bin/bundle:23 in load
/usr/local/bin/bundle:23 in <main>
```

Logs: https://pastebin.com/M0mM2Zsf

Edited to show the complete stack trace for the error as per pastebin

```
1592916416204,"Started PUT ""/questionnaire_responses/asda67SdD787a8sddadclmgh_eerw09/edit"" for 198.41.0.0 at 2020-06-23 12:46:56 +0000"
1592916416205,Processing by PublicQuestionnaireResponsesController#update as */*
1592916416206,"  Parameters: {""draft_button""=>""true"", ""authenticity_token""=>""cCGRhCDe6SUNDWKdsZ+WHT2BdLdGCHS8X1or9lJRIQBkoyRdabBgrUo+k+RCvsLMvBkk9myrnsmIiLkwOZ/Q1g=="", ""questionnaire_response""=>{""answers_attributes""=>{""4464407""=>{""question_id""=>""4464407"", ""files""=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000000000c5f4fb8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20200623-22-10wkf6r.pdf>, @original_filename=""Sep 19.pdf"", @content_type=""application/pdf"", @headers=""Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\""questionnaire_response[answers_attributes][4464407][files][]\""; filename=\""Sep 19.pdf\""\r
Content-Type: application/pdf\r
"">]}, ""4464406""=>{""question_id""=>""4464406"", ""files""=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000000000c5f4dd8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20200623-22-1ngl7kh.pdf>, @original_filename=""My PDF Sept 19, 2018.pdf"", @content_type=""application/pdf"", @headers=""Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\""questionnaire_response[answers_attributes][4464406][files][]\""; filename=\""My PDF Sept 19, 2018.pdf\""\r
Content-Type: application/pdf\r
"">]}, ""4464411""=>{""question_id""=>""4464411""}}}, ""_""=>""B728eVb0cPYcSgo3M_B7c"", ""id""=>""asda67SdD787a8sddadclmgh_eerw09""}"
1592916416208,"  [1m[36mAccount Load (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  ""accounts"".* FROM ""accounts"" WHERE ""accounts"".""subdomain"" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [[""subdomain"", ""customer-inc""], [""LIMIT"", 1]]"
1592916416210,"  [1m[36mAccount Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  ""accounts"".* FROM ""accounts"" WHERE ""accounts"".""subdomain"" = $1 ORDER BY ""accounts"".""id"" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [[""subdomain"", ""customer-inc""], [""LIMIT"", 1]]"
1592916416213,"  [1m[36mQuestionnaire::QuestionnaireResponse Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  ""questionnaire_responses"".* FROM ""questionnaire_responses"" WHERE ""questionnaire_responses"".""uid"" = $1 AND (""questionnaire_responses"".""done"" = $2 OR ""questionnaire_responses"".""done"" IS NULL) LIMIT $3[0m  [[""uid"", ""asda67SdD787a8sddadclmgh_eerw09""], [""done"", false], [""LIMIT"", 1]]"
1592916416215,"  [1m[36mQuestionnaire Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT ""questionnaires"".* FROM ""questionnaires"" WHERE ""questionnaires"".""id"" = $1[0m  [[""id"", 379305]]"
1592916416217,"  [1m[36mQuestionnaire::QuestionnaireItem Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT ""questionnaire_items"".* FROM ""questionnaire_items"" WHERE ""questionnaire_items"".""questionnaire_id"" = $1[0m  [[""questionnaire_id"", 379305]]"
1592916416220,"  [1m[36mQuestion Load (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT ""questions"".* FROM ""questions"" WHERE ""questions"".""id"" IN ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13) ORDER BY questions.position ASC, questions.id ASC[0m  [[""id"", 4464412], [""id"", 4464411], [""id"", 4464409], [""id"", 4464408], [""id"", 4464407], [""id"", 4464406], [""id"", 4463448], [""id"", 4463435], [""id"", 4463434], [""id"", 4463433], [""id"", 4463431], [""id"", 4463429], [""id"", 4463423]]"
1592916416222,"  [1m[36mPageBreak Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT ""page_breaks"".* FROM ""page_breaks"" WHERE ""page_breaks"".""id"" IN ($1, $2, $3)[0m  [[""id"", 360685], [""id"", 360603], [""id"", 360602]]"
1592916416225,"  [1m[36mQuestionnaire::SupportingFile Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT ""questionnaire_supporting_files"".* FROM ""questionnaire_supporting_files"" WHERE ""questionnaire_supporting_files"".""questionnaire_id"" = $1[0m  [[""questionnaire_id"", 379305]]"
1592916416227,"  [1m[36mProject Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT ""projects"".* FROM ""projects"" WHERE ""projects"".""id"" = $1 ORDER BY LOWER(projects.name)[0m  [[""id"", 119686]]"
1592916416229,"  [1m[36mAccount Load (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT ""accounts"".* FROM ""accounts"" WHERE ""accounts"".""id"" = $1[0m  [[""id"", 123456]]"
1592916416231,"  [1m[36mUser Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  ""users"".* FROM ""users"" WHERE ""users"".""email"" IS NULL LIMIT $1[0m  [[""LIMIT"", 1]]"
1592916416233,"  [1m[36mUser Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  ""users"".* FROM ""users"" INNER JOIN ""accounts_users"" ON ""users"".""id"" = ""accounts_users"".""user_id"" WHERE ""accounts_users"".""account_id"" = $1 AND ""users"".""email"" IS NULL LIMIT $2[0m  [[""account_id"", 123456], [""LIMIT"", 1]]"
1592916416235,  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
1592916416236,"  [1m[36mUser Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  ""users"".* FROM ""users"" WHERE ""users"".""id"" = $1 ORDER BY ""users"".""id"" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [[""id"", 149890], [""LIMIT"", 1]]"
1592916416239,"  [1m[35m (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT ""questions"".""id"" FROM ""questions"" WHERE ""questions"".""questionnaire_id"" = $1 ORDER BY questions.position ASC, questions.id ASC[0m  [[""questionnaire_id"", 379305]]"
1592916416241,"  [1m[36mAnswer Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT ""answers"".* FROM ""answers"" WHERE ""answers"".""questionnaire_response_id"" = $1[0m  [[""questionnaire_response_id"", 8072287]]"
1592916416243,"  [1m[36mQuestion Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT ""questions"".* FROM ""questions"" WHERE ""questions"".""id"" IN ($1, $2, $3, $4) ORDER BY questions.position ASC, questions.id ASC[0m  [[""id"", 4463448], [""id"", 4463431], [""id"", 4463429], [""id"", 4463423]]"
1592916416248,"  [1m[36mQuestion Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  ""questions"".* FROM ""questions"" WHERE ""questions"".""id"" = $1 ORDER BY questions.position ASC, questions.id ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [[""id"", 4464407], [""LIMIT"", 1]]"
1592916416251,"  [1m[36mAnswer Create (0.6ms)[0m  [1m[32mINSERT INTO ""answers"" (""question_id"", ""questionnaire_response_id"", ""files"", ""created_at"", ""updated_at"") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING ""id""[0m  [[""question_id"", 4464407], [""questionnaire_response_id"", 8072287], [""files"", ""---
- Sep_19.pdf
""], [""created_at"", ""2020-06-23 12:46:56.250131""], [""updated_at"", ""2020-06-23 12:46:56.250131""]]"
1592916416390,"  [1m[36mQuestion Load (0.6ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  ""questions"".* FROM ""questions"" WHERE ""questions"".""id"" = $1 ORDER BY questions.position ASC, questions.id ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [[""id"", 4464406], [""LIMIT"", 1]]"
1592916416393,"  [1m[36mAnswer Create (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[32mINSERT INTO ""answers"" (""question_id"", ""questionnaire_response_id"", ""files"", ""created_at"", ""updated_at"") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING ""id""[0m  [[""question_id"", 4464406], [""questionnaire_response_id"", 8072287], [""files"", ""---
- My_PDF_Sept_19__2018.pdf
""], [""created_at"", ""2020-06-23 12:46:56.391887""], [""updated_at"", ""2020-06-23 12:46:56.391887""]]"
1592916416489,"  [1m[36mQuestion Load (0.7ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  ""questions"".* FROM ""questions"" WHERE ""questions"".""id"" = $1 ORDER BY questions.position ASC, questions.id ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [[""id"", 4464411], [""LIMIT"", 1]]"
1592916416496,  [1m[35m (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[31mROLLBACK[0m
1592916416498,Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 292ms (ActiveRecord: 8.9ms)
1592916416501,[analytics-ruby] Sending request for 1 items
1592916416507,
1592916416509,TypeError (no _dump_data is defined for class OpenSSL::Digest):
1592916416509,
1592916416509,app/models/questionnaire/questionnaire_response.rb:290:in `block in process_answers'
1592916416509,[uuid: 939e755ed429cb6fdf6f39e96040dd28] [user_uid: xkZGncsu_vCc] [subdomain: customer-inc] app/models/questionnaire/questionnaire_response.rb:283:in `process_answers'
1592916416509,[uuid: 939e755ed429cb6fdf6f39e96040dd28] [user_uid: xkZGncsu_vCc] [subdomain: customer-inc] app/models/questionnaire/questionnaire_response.rb:218:in `assign_params'
1592916416509,[uuid: 939e755ed429cb6fdf6f39e96040dd28] [user_uid: xkZGncsu_vCc] [subdomain: customer-inc] app/models/questionnaire/questionnaire_response.rb:155:in `save_draft'
1592916416509,[uuid: 939e755ed429cb6fdf6f39e96040dd28] [user_uid: xkZGncsu_vCc] [subdomain: customer-inc] app/interactors/questionnaire/update_questionnaire_response.rb:53:in `save_draft'
1592916416509,[uuid: 939e755ed429cb6fdf6f39e96040dd28] [user_uid: xkZGncsu_vCc] [subdomain: customer-inc] app/interactors/questionnaire/update_questionnaire_response.rb:19:in `call'
1592916416509,[uuid: 939e755ed429cb6fdf6f39e96040dd28] [user_uid: xkZGncsu_vCc] [subdomain: customer-inc] app/controllers/public_questionnaire_responses_controller.rb:56:in `update_questionnaire_response'
1592916416509,[uuid: 939e755ed429cb6fdf6f39e96040dd28] [user_uid: xkZGncsu_vCc] [subdomain: customer-inc] app/controllers/public_questionnaire_responses_controller.rb:31:in `block in update'
1592916416509,[uuid: 939e755ed429cb6fdf6f39e96040dd28] [user_uid: xkZGncsu_vCc] [subdomain: customer-inc] app/controllers/public_questionnaire_responses_controller.rb:27:in `update'
1592916416509,[uuid: 939e755ed429cb6fdf6f39e96040dd28] [user_uid: xkZGncsu_vCc] [subdomain: customer-inc] app/controllers/public_questionnaire_responses_controller.rb:122:in `block in set_response_locale'
1592916416509,[uuid: 939e755ed429cb6fdf6f39e96040dd28] [user_uid: xkZGncsu_vCc] [subdomain: customer-inc] app/controllers/public_questionnaire_responses_controller.rb:122:in `set_response_locale'
1592916416510,Processing by GrcShared::ErrorsController#show as */*
1592916416510,"  Parameters: {""draft_button""=>""true"", ""authenticity_token""=>""cCGRhCDe6SUNDWKdsZ+WHT2BdLdGCHS8X1or9lJRIQBkoyRdabBgrUo+k+RCvsLMvBkk9myrnsmIiLkwOZ/Q1g=="", ""questionnaire_response""=>{""answers_attributes""=>{""4464407""=>{""question_id""=>""4464407"", ""files""=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000000000c5f4fb8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20200623-22-10wkf6r.pdf>, @original_filename=""Sep 19.pdf"", @content_type=""application/pdf"", @headers=""Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\""questionnaire_response[answers_attributes][4464407][files][]\""; filename=\""Sep 19.pdf\""\r
Content-Type: application/pdf\r
"">]}, ""4464406""=>{""question_id""=>""4464406"", ""files""=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000000000c5f4dd8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20200623-22-1ngl7kh.pdf>, @original_filename=""My PDF Sept 19, 2018.pdf"", @content_type=""application/pdf"", @headers=""Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\""questionnaire_response[answers_attributes][4464406][files][]\""; filename=\""My PDF Sept 19, 2018.pdf\""\r
Content-Type: application/pdf\r
"">]}, ""4464411""=>{""question_id""=>""4464411""}}}, ""_""=>""B728eVb0cPYcSgo3M_B7c"", ""id""=>""asda67SdD787a8sddadclmgh_eerw09""}"
1592916416525,  Rendering vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/gems/grc_shared-cf61a08e39dd/app/views/grc_shared/errors/_show.erb
1592916416527,  Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/gems/grc_shared-cf61a08e39dd/app/views/grc_shared/errors/_show.erb (1.7ms)
1592916416529,Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 19ms (Views: 16.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

It only happens for that one controller and action.

The model is called `Answer` and it has a couple of validations, mostly `presence: true` with a bunch of different conditions whether to validate the answer value or not (e.g. required vs optional). The parameters looks something like this:

```
{
  "_method": "put",
  "aclui-uploader": {
    "content_type": "application/pdf",
    "headers": "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"aclui-uploader\"; filename=\"Jan 1.pdf\"\r\nContent-Type: application/pdf\r\n",
    "original_filename": "Jan 1.pdf",
    "tempfile": "#<File:0x000000000c3af9b0>"
  },
  "action": "update",
  "authenticity_token": "[Filtered]",
  "controller": "public_questionnaire_responses",
  "draft_button": "true",
  "id": "7sk8PPpb_KdV_h1jzXsP",
  "questionnaire_response": {
    "answers_attributes": {
      "581102": {
        "question_id": "581102"
      },
      "581111": {
        "question_id": "581111",
        "value": ""
      },
      "581124": {
        "files": [
          {
            "content_type": "application/pdf",
            "headers": "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"questionnaire_response[answers_attributes][581124][files][]\"; filename=\"Jan 1.pdf\"\r\nContent-Type: application/pdf\r\n",
            "original_filename": "Jan 1.pdf",
            "tempfile": "#<File:0x000000000c347ea0>"
          }
        ],
        "question_id": "581124"
      },
      "581128": {
        "question_id": "581128",
        "value": "ABC"
      },
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

At times the error rate is as high as 13% of the requests to this endpoint, but often much lower and at times not happening at all:
[image: endpoint error rate]

Another mystery is why it's mostly happening in just one of our regions. We deploy to multiple AWS regions, US being our biggest region but only generating <20% of the errors, vs AP being a smaller region generating almost 80% of the errors (another medium sized region with <1%).

Let me know if I can provide any additional details.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: added the rest of the stacktrace (below `app/models/questionnaire/questionnaire_response.rb:283 in process_answers`)

EDIT: added logs in pastebin (https://pastebin.com/M0mM2Zsf)

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace, you are missing all the important info. Thanks

Comment: This could be related to caching and translations. But no idea what, hoping the full trace will provide a clue

Comment: @jamesc Thanks for having a look! Yea caching and translations might be involved - I'm just confused how `OpenSSL::Digest` comes into play there. Maybe because of the file in the multi-part request payload? We're not caching anything manually. And I think the translations only kick in for some basic presence validation

Comment: Post the full stack trace please

Comment: @jamesc I updated the question with the full stack trace - that's all I got from Airbrake. You figured there is something missing?

Comment: Yes, a stack trace starts with the request type i.e. POST GET etc... and the controller name followed by the parameters. There is a lot missing

Comment: You will see the parameters passed to the controller then you can reproduce the error for yourself and track it down

Comment: You will get the proper stack trace from your log file

Comment: @jamesc the airbrake contains the full stack trace. there is no additional stack trace (not even the full one) in the logs. However I uploaded the logs anyways in case anything in there helps: https://pastebin.com/M0mM2Zsf

Comment: As you can see, I have added the complete stack trace for the request to your question from the pastebin. Now we can clearly see the method that was called, the parameters that were used and the lines of code causing the problem. You should be able to use that information to tracvk down your issue by posting exactly the same parameters to the same controller/action in your development environment.

Comment: You should get hold of the pdf's and see if there is any content in them that is causing the problem. that may be a red herring though.

Comment: Is there a problem with the data in reading question id 4464411

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216527/discussion-between-axelthegerman-and-jamesc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a bit too early to say for sure but we might have solved it by removing the following two line from our `config/initializers/i18n.rb`

```
I18n::Backend::Simple.send(:include, I18n::Backend::Cache)
I18n.cache_store = ActiveSupport::Cache.lookup_store(:memory_store)
```

In the 2 weeks before deploying this changes the errors already dropped from up to 1k errors/day to single or double digits.

Directly after deploy we haven't seen a single one in 2 days.

I'm not sure if there is any performance impact of removing that caching - but I noticed our other rails apps don't have this.

Comment: 6 months in and the error has not re-occured

Answer (score 2):

### This is a general error with cache

Errors like `no _dump_data is defined` and `no marshal_dump is defined`occurs in majority in cache implementations and is dificulty to know where error occurs.

To fix this gerenic error I suggest to investigate all new `GEMs/features/edits` because in some part the implementation is not getting turn general data in "cached data".

For example in my actual implementation I get this error when try to use `searchkick` with `view_components_reflexes` (who cacheable all data). I need to adjust how send data to view_components_reflex to work.

Comment: Thanks Jonatas, I wonder if some gem upgrades caused it in our case. But the solution we put in place (removing some custom cache set up) as resolved it for us :)

Answer (score 0):

## Root Cause

The error's root cause comes from Marshalling an object with an [HTTP connection](https://file:///home/aaron/Code/Ruby/Docs/ruby_3_1_1_stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) as an [instance variable](https://file:///home/aaron/Code/Ruby/Docs/ruby_3_1_1_core/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Instance+Variables).

From the [Marshal docs](https://file:///home/aaron/Code/Ruby/Docs/ruby_3_1_1_core/Marshal.html):

> Some objects cannot be dumped: if the objects to be dumped include bindings, procedure or method objects, instances of class IO, or singleton objects, a TypeError will be raised.

### Additional Info

In this case, the connection is an HTTPS connection (thus the 'OpenSSL etc' portion of the error). However, the same root problem would still exist with an HTTP connection (in that case the error would read something like "can't dump TCPSocket").

This does not come from the fact that the HTTP connection is open. Even if [`HTTP.finish`](https://file:///home/aaron/Code/Ruby/Docs/ruby_3_1_1_stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-finish) is called, the error will persist. Strangely, if the connection is not started to begin with the error is avoided.

## Solution

Personally I first would recommend Marshalling not be used at all in a publicly-facing context, due to the security concerns.

However, if the decision is made to use Marshalling and if the code is able to be altered, the correct approach would be to implement your own serialization strategy. Again from [the docs](https://file:///home/aaron/Code/Ruby/Docs/ruby_3_1_1_core/Marshal.html):

> If your class has special serialization needs (for example, if you want to serialize in some specific format), or if it contains objects that would otherwise not be serializable, you can implement your own serialization strategy.

If the problem resides in a Gem or code from another party, a bug report is in order.

## Examples

Sample minimum viable example:

```rb
def make_error
  require 'net/http'

  uri = URI('https://localhost:5010')
  @http_conn = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  @http_conn.use_ssl = true
  @http_conn.start
  Marshal.dump(self)
end
```

Making the connection a local variable instead of an instance variable avoids the error:

```rb
def make_error
  require 'net/http'

  uri = URI('https://localhost:5010')
  http_conn = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http_conn.use_ssl = true
  http_conn.start
  Marshal.dump(self)
end
```

Comment: It is also possible to sidestep the issue by closing the connection and re-assigning the instance variable before Marshalling, like `@http_conn = nil`.